# Yii framework,CGridView Checkbox help

Tags: php, yii

I want an alert that pops when user tries to click "add to favorite"
1) if there's no checkboxes checked.
2) I also want to know how to get the values of the checked boxes 
 here's my current code on backend

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',array(
'id' => 'wsrecruitcvhead-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
#'filter' => $model,
'columns' => array(
    array(
      'name' =>'',
      'value' => 'CHtml::checkBox("rid[]",null,array("value"=>$data->ResumeID,"id"=>"rid_".$data->ResumeID))',
      'type'=>'raw',
      'htmlOptions' => array('width'=>5),
      'visible' => !Yii::app()->user->isGuest,
    ),
    array(
       'name' => 'ResumeTitle',
       'value' =>$model->ResumeTitle,
    ),
    'ResumeSummaryIntroduction',
    'Name',
    array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        'viewButtonUrl' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("wsrecruitcvhead/view",array("id"=>$data["ResumeID"]))',
        'template'=>'{view}',
    ),
),
```

));
?>

and here's the screen shot `http://pastebin.com/sEpJBCiU`

Comment: Something is wrong with the screenshot, please check.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps you.

Your code works just fine, just tried it. I would implement the functionality you mentioned using jQuery, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    var thisCheck = $(this);
    if (thisCheck.is (':checked')){
        // do what you want here, the way to access the text is using the
        // $(this) selector. The following code would output pop up message with
        // the selected checkbox text
        $(this).val());
    }
});
</script>
```

This code selects all those DOM elements of type checkbox, and then checks with the if condition if it is selected or not. [Here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-checkbox-checked-event) you can find more information about this jQuery selector. jQuery is such a powerful tool!!

Answer (score 2):

For get all seleccions of a Grid yii provides the follow code

```
var seleccions = ($.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection('id_my_cgridview'));
```

this return an array with the values of checkboxes selected

Comment: I love that you are consistent with your typos